executing in slime lisp does not execute
This code works when launched like this: clisp test.lisp
;;contents of test.lisp file
(defun wtof (filename text)
  "Append TEXT to the file specified by FILENAME."
  (with-open-file (stream filename :direction :output :element-type 'character :if-does-not-exist :create :if-exists :append)
    (write-string text stream)))

(wtof "test.c" "/* hello world */")

But I'd like to use slime to type last line (wtof "test.c" "/* hello world */") and have things written into test.c file. Is that possible? Slime gives an error.

What error does it give? [emacs.se] may be a better place to ask Slime-specific questions.

It works for me. Did you load the test.lisp file into the REPL? What error did you get?

When I do ^c^k - it works, but if I do ^c^c on a function definition, then do ^c^c on function call (wtof.. it gives me an error

Please be more specific than "gives an error".
